# How to call a function from truffle

Tags: truffle, testrpc

I'm new to ethereum. I followed a tutorial and I ended up with a contract that looks like this

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;
contract HelloWorld {
  uint public balance;

  function HelloWorld()  {
      balance = 1000;
  }

  function deposit(uint _value)  returns (uint _newValue) {
      balance += _value;
      return balance;
  }
}
```

After the contract is deployed at testrpc I try to call the deposit function with respect to the recent changes in syntax like so:

```
var hw = HelloWorld.deployed();
hw.then(function(i){
 return i.deposit(500)
})
.then(function(r){
  console.log(r)
})
```

but I get a Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
How do I call this function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
this.HelloWorld
      .deployed()
      .then(instance => {
        return instance.deposit(500,{
          from: this.account
        });
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo!
However, if I do it like that I get 'Error: invalid address'.
If I replace this.account with web3.eth.accounts[0] i get 'invalid opcode' again.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I assumed you had assigned this.account to web3.eth.accounts[0].
Then, there must be a problem with the contract. Is that all the code there is to it?

Comment: That's all the code. I just discovered ether does get subtracted from the account, even though there's that error msg (opcode)

Comment: ok, it was stupid. I just restarted testrpc, recompiled and migrated the contract again, and now it works.